# How can I pass these barriers or must I restart the quest?

Tags: diablo-iii

While exploring the archives for the 2nd seal to restore Zoltun I found a room that was stacked with strong enemies.  I chose to retreat back through the doorway but found myself sealed off from the battle.

My templar and my spider could not cross the barrier, but if the enemies come close enough we can hit them for a few points of damage.

I suspect that I need to destroy the arcane construct to lower the field and so I fear that I'll have to backtrack a bit.

Is there any way to drop this door or is it a glitch?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had ran into this with me and 2 of my friends, when the wall is up nothing can pass through. The only way we were able to pass is when the one person in the room killed all the creatures and opened the chest in the room (The last creature died as he opened the chest so I am not sure if there is a connection.)

Answer (score -1):

These doors should block your spells but you should be able to walk right through them. I have never seen them block the character so if they are that seems to be either a glitch or you found some odd mechanic I've never triggered.

Comment: When they are yellow and "sandy" you can walk through them, when the round ancient construct appears and the go flame red you cannot.

Comment: Ok then I've never seen that happen before. Sorry.